# maxHeight of MUI TextField Select Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to set a maximum height in a MUI TextField with select property. I want to set the maximum height for the menu:

```
<TextField
        fullWidth
        label="Select State"
        name="state"
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        select
        SelectProps={{ native: true }}
        value={values.state}
>
        {states.map((option) => (
                 <option
                          key={option.value}
                          value={option.value}
                 >
                          {option.label}
                 </option>
        ))}
</TextField>
```

I tried to use `MenuProps`, which works for the `Select` component, but not for a `TextField`:

```
<TextField
        ...
        SelectProps={{
                  MenuProps: {
                          sx: { maxHeight: 200 }
                  }
        }}
        ...
</TextField>
```

I also tried setting `sx` and `style` properties in `TextField`.

How can I style this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MUI creates the `TextField` component using an interesting mix of native HTML elements, pseudo-elements, states and events. A simple `size` attribute that behaves like the native [HTML Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) input field does not exist for `TextField`. Due to mix of elements used, the `TextField` `SelectProps={{native:true}}` prop cannot be used if you want to limit the height of the menu options. MUI's `MenuItem`s are needed to control the menu height. Perhaps the best solution is to use [Theme style overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides) which is demonstrated below.

### MuiPopover styleOverrides

The style override looks like this:

```
const theme = createTheme( {
    components: {
        MuiPopover: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    '&#menu-TEXTFIELD_IDENTIFIER .MuiPaper-root.MuiMenu-paper.MuiPaper-elevation.MuiPaper-rounded.MuiPopover-paper': {
                        maxHeight: '86px' // Example maximum of two options displayed. About 43px per select option.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

The component used to display select menu options is a [MuiPopover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/). A style override is used because this component cannot be easily selected using CSS selector rules with the **sx** property. MuiPopover is neither a sibling nor a descendant of the root element used for `TextField`.

In the style override above, **TEXTFIELD_IDENTIFIER** is the **id** you assign to the `id` property of the `TextField` component. `TextField` assigns the prefix **menu-** to the `id` when generating the MuiPopover. Using this `id` as part of the style override selector prevents the override from affecting every MuiPopover in your application.

### Demo

Sample code is below. A [live demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76007908) for the code is available.

In the demo, two select fields are displayed, but only the first is affected by the style override. Although `ThemeProvider` is used here, it would typically be applied at the application entry point.

### app.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Box,
    TextField,
    MenuItem
} from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

interface selectOption {
    value: string
}

const theme = createTheme( {
    components: {
        MuiPopover: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    '&#menu-first-select-box .MuiPaper-root.MuiMenu-paper.MuiPaper-elevation.MuiPaper-rounded.MuiPopover-paper': {
                        maxHeight: '86px' // About 43px per select option.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );


export default function ColorTextFields() {
    const [ firstValue, setFirstValue ] = React.useState( 'One' );
    const [ secondValue, setSecondValue ] = React.useState( 'Six' );

    const firstOptions: selectOption[] = [
        { value: 'One' },
        { value: 'Two' },
        { value: 'Three' },
        { value: 'Four' },
        { value: 'Five' }
    ];

    const secondOptions: selectOption[] = [
        { value: 'Six' },
        { value: 'Seven' },
        { value: 'Eight' },
        { value: 'Nine' },
        { value: 'Ten' }
    ];


    function handleFirstChange( e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) {
        setFirstValue( e.target.value );
    }


    function handleSecondChange( e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) {
        setSecondValue( e.target.value );
    }


    function buildOptions( option: selectOption ): React.ReactElement<typeof MenuItem> {
        return (
            <MenuItem
                key={ option.value }
                id={ option.value }
                value={ option.value }
            >
                { option.value }
            </MenuItem>
        )
    }


    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
            <Box
                component="form"
                sx={{
                    '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' }
                }}
                noValidate
                autoComplete="off"
            >
                <TextField
                    id={ 'first-select-box' }
                    name={ 'first-select-box' }
                    label="First Select"
                    select
                    SelectProps={ { native: false } }
                    variant="standard"
                    value={ firstValue }
                    onChange={ handleFirstChange }
                >
                    { firstOptions.map( buildOptions ) }
                </TextField>

                <TextField
                    id={ 'second-select-box' }
                    name={ 'second-select-box' }
                    label="Second select"
                    select
                    SelectProps={ { native: false } }
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={ secondValue }
                    onChange={ handleSecondChange }
                >
                    { secondOptions.map( buildOptions ) }
                </TextField>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i did this and it helps

```
      <TextField
        select
        label="label"
        variant="standard"
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            sx: { height: "300px" },
          },
        }}
      >
  /// your code here
      </TextField>
```